# How to reload one file on Express without restarting?

Tags: node.js, express, fs

I am appending a new route to a route JavaScript file with fs.appendFileSync(...), but, as Node.Js needs to be restarted to reload files, the appended route cannot be accessed. I only need to reload the file that is being appeded to.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = router;

/* New Routes are appended here.
Example:

router.get('/bobby', function(req, res, next){

});
 */
```

I've already searched Stack Overflow on ways to reload files without restarting the server, but all of the questions only involve the automated reloading for development, not the real thing. I've seen the suggestions for Nodemon and Node-Supervisor already, but those say it is just for development.

This may be a dumb question, but I don't know how to solve it.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: So you have code modifying code, is that right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: It's an attempt at dynamic routing.

Comment: He's saying controllers. Is that the same as a route?

Comment: Sorry, the link was inadequate... I'm not too sure you could do it this way in Node. You would if you were working with Clojure or Erlang... Node is not designed for code modification. Why not simply call `app.use/get/...` at runtime ? The very purpose of these functions is to add routers.

Comment: Okay, let me look into that.

Comment: You could do this much easier using dynamic routes (e.g. `/:route`).

Comment: I want to access the route at a later time also.

Comment: Well you see I was all wrong. Danziger has it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`require-reload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-reload) to do that. You should have a file where you import the `router.js` module, to which you are appending new code, that should look like:

```
var reload = require('require-reload')(require),
var router = reload('router.js');
```

Each time you append new code you should do:

```
try {
    router = reload('router.js');
} catch (e) {
    console.error("Failed to reload router.js! Error: ", e);
}
```

The [`express-route-refresh`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-route-refresh) module may come in handy too. In fact, internally it also uses [`require-reload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-reload).